# QGIS Python script for creating project file

Tags: qgis, python, standalone, qgs

Is there a way to create QGIS project file(`.qgs`) using only Python script outside QGIS Python console. I am trying to publish a map using QGIS Web Client using python.

For this, I am trying to do below

1. Create `.qgs` file dynamically
2. Add Legend and Layers to the `.qgs` file and save
3. Set WFS,WCS parameters in the `.qgs` file

Finally use this file to view QGIS web client.

I tried to tweak the tool available at https://github.com/oware/Mxd2Qgs. I am successful to certain extent, i.e. creating a `.qgs` file. But I need some inputs on Getting layer (vector/raster) properties when path for the files is given.

## code below

```
# Import system modules
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import string
import os
import glob


#Read input parameters from GP dialog
output = "myworld.qgs"

#Create an output qgs file
f = open(output, "w")

# Create the minidom
doc = Document()

# Create the <qgis> base element
qgis = doc.createElement("qgis")
qgis.setAttribute("projectname", " ")
qgis.setAttribute("version", "2.4.0-Chugiak")
doc.appendChild(qgis)

# Create the <title> element
title = doc.createElement("title")
qgis.appendChild(title)


unit = doc.createTextNode("degrees")
xmin1 = doc.createTextNode(str("-180"))
ymin1 = doc.createTextNode(str("-90"))
xmax1 = doc.createTextNode(str("180"))
ymax1 = doc.createTextNode(str("90"))
proj4id = doc.createTextNode(str("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
srid1 = doc.createTextNode(str("4326"))
srid2 = doc.createTextNode(str("3452"))
epsg1 = doc.createTextNode(str("4326"))
epsg2 = doc.createTextNode(str("4326"))
description1 = doc.createTextNode(str("WGS 84"))
description2 = doc.createTextNode(str("WGS 84"))
ellipsoidacronym1 = doc.createTextNode(str("WGS84"))
ellipsoidacronym2 = doc.createTextNode(str("WGS84"))
geographicflag1 = doc.createTextNode("true")
geographicflag2 = doc.createTextNode("true")
pa=doc.createTextNode("longlat")
authid2 = doc.createTextNode("EPSG:"+str("4326"))
authid3 = doc.createTextNode("EPSG:"+str("4326"))
count2=0
# mapcanvas
def map_canvas():
    # Create the <mapcanvas> element
    mapcanvas = doc.createElement("mapcanvas")
    qgis.appendChild(mapcanvas)

# Create the <units> element
units = doc.createElement("units")
units.appendChild(unit)
mapcanvas.appendChild(units)

# Create the <extent> element
extent = doc.createElement("extent")
mapcanvas.appendChild(extent)

# Create the <xmin> element
xmin = doc.createElement("xmin")
xmin.appendChild(xmin1)
extent.appendChild(xmin)

# Create the <ymin> element
ymin = doc.createElement("ymin")
ymin.appendChild(ymin1)
extent.appendChild(ymin)

# Create the <xmax> element
xmax = doc.createElement("xmax")
xmax.appendChild(xmax1)
extent.appendChild(xmax)

# Create the <ymax> element
ymax = doc.createElement("ymax")
ymax.appendChild(ymax1)
extent.appendChild(ymax)

# Create the <projections> element
projections = doc.createElement("projections")
mapcanvas.appendChild(projections)

# Create the <destinationsrs> element
destinationsrs = doc.createElement("destinationsrs")
mapcanvas.appendChild(destinationsrs)

# Create the <spatialrefsys> element
spatialrefsys = doc.createElement("spatialrefsys")
destinationsrs.appendChild(spatialrefsys)

# Create the <proj4> element
proj4 = doc.createElement("proj4")
proj4.appendChild(proj4id)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(proj4)

# Create the <srsid> element
srsid = doc.createElement("srsid")
srsid.appendChild(srid2)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(srsid)

# Create the <srid> element
srid = doc.createElement("srid")
srid.appendChild(srid1)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(srid)

# Create the <authid> element
authid = doc.createElement("authid")
authid.appendChild(authid2)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(authid)

# Create the <description> element
description = doc.createElement("description")
description.appendChild(description1)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(description)

# Create the <projectionacronym> element
projectionacronym = doc.createElement("projectionacronym")
spatialrefsys.appendChild(projectionacronym)
projectionacronym.appendChild(pa)

# Create the <ellipsoidacronym element
ellipsoidacronym = doc.createElement("ellipsoidacronym")
ellipsoidacronym.appendChild(ellipsoidacronym1)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(ellipsoidacronym)

# Create the <geographicflag> element
geographicflag = doc.createElement("geographicflag")
geographicflag.appendChild(geographicflag1)
spatialrefsys.appendChild(geographicflag)



# Legend
# Legend
def legend_func():
    global count2
    # Create the <legend> element
    legend = doc.createElement("legend")
    qgis.appendChild(legend)


for lyr in os.listdir(r"C:\Build\xyz\shapefiles"):
     if lyr.endswith('.shp'):
        count2=count2+1 
        print lyr
        print "\n"
        # Create the <legendlayer> element
        legendlayer = doc.createElement("legendlayer")
        legendlayer.setAttribute("open", "true")
        legendlayer.setAttribute("checked", "Qt::Checked")
        legendlayer.setAttribute("name",lyr)

        legend.appendChild(legendlayer)

        # Create the <filegroup> element
        filegroup = doc.createElement("filegroup")
        filegroup.setAttribute("open", "true")
        filegroup.setAttribute("hidden", "false")
        legendlayer.appendChild(filegroup)

        # Create the <legendlayerfile> element
        legendlayerfile = doc.createElement("legendlayerfile")
        legendlayerfile.setAttribute("isInOverview", "0")
        legendlayerfile.setAttribute("layerid", lyr+str(20110427170816078))
        legendlayerfile.setAttribute("visible", "1")
        filegroup.appendChild(legendlayerfile)


# Project Layers
def project_layers():  
    # Create the <projectlayers> element
    projectlayers = doc.createElement("projectlayers")
    count1=str(count2)
    projectlayers.setAttribute("layercount", count1)
    qgis.appendChild(projectlayers)

for lyr in os.listdir(r"C:\Build\xyz\shapefiles"):

    if lyr.endswith('.shp'):

        print lyr
        print "\n"
        ds = doc.createTextNode(str(r"C:\Build\xyz\shapefiles"+"\\"+lyr))
        #Tool fails here as there is dependency on ArcGIS
        #Is there a way to replace below 2 lines ,with equivalents from QGIS?
        geometry1 = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        geometry2 = str(geometry1.shapeType)

        name1 = doc.createTextNode(lyr+str(20110427170816078))
        name2 = doc.createTextNode(lyr)

       # Create the <maplayer> element
        maplayer = doc.createElement("maplayer")
        maplayer.setAttribute("minimumScale", "0")
        maplayer.setAttribute("maximumScale", "1e+08")
        maplayer.setAttribute("minLabelScale", "0")
        maplayer.setAttribute("maxLabelScale", "1e+08")
        maplayer.setAttribute("geometry", geometry2)
        maplayer.setAttribute("type", "vector")
        maplayer.setAttribute("hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag", "0")
        maplayer.setAttribute("scaleBasedLabelVisibilityFlag", "0")
        projectlayers.appendChild(maplayer)

        # Create the <id> element
        id = doc.createElement("id")
        id.appendChild(name1)
        maplayer.appendChild(id)

        # Create the <datasource> element
        datasource = doc.createElement("datasource")
        datasource.appendChild(ds)
        maplayer.appendChild(datasource)

        # Create the <layername> element
        layername = doc.createElement("layername")
        layername.appendChild(name2)
        maplayer.appendChild(layername)

        # Create the <srs> element
        srs = doc.createElement("srs")
        maplayer.appendChild(srs)

        # Create the <spatialrefsys> element
        spatialrefsys = doc.createElement("spatialrefsys")
        srs.appendChild(spatialrefsys)

        # Create the <proj4> element
        proj4 = doc.createElement("proj4")
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(proj4)

        # Create the <srsid> element
        srsid = doc.createElement("srsid")
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(srsid)

        # Create the <srid> element
        srid = doc.createElement("srid")
        srid.appendChild(srid2)
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(srid)


        # Create the <authid> element
        authid = doc.createElement("authid")
        authid.appendChild(authid3)
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(authid)


        # Create the <description> element
        description = doc.createElement("description")
        description.appendChild(description2)
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(description)


        # Create the <projectionacronym> element
        projectionacronym = doc.createElement("projectionacronym")
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(projectionacronym)

        # Create the <ellipsoidacronym element
        ellipsoidacronym = doc.createElement("ellipsoidacronym")
        ellipsoidacronym.appendChild(ellipsoidacronym2)
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(ellipsoidacronym)


        # Create the <geographicflag> element
        geographicflag = doc.createElement("geographicflag")
        geographicflag.appendChild(geographicflag2)
        spatialrefsys.appendChild(geographicflag)

        # Create the <transparencyLevelInt> element
        transparencyLevelInt = doc.createElement("transparencyLevelInt")
        transparency2 = doc.createTextNode("255")
        transparencyLevelInt.appendChild(transparency2)
        maplayer.appendChild(transparencyLevelInt)

        # Create the <customproperties> element
        customproperties = doc.createElement("customproperties")
        maplayer.appendChild(customproperties)

        # Create the <provider> element
        provider = doc.createElement("provider")
        provider.setAttribute("encoding", "System")
        ogr = doc.createTextNode("ogr")
        provider.appendChild(ogr)
        maplayer.appendChild(provider)

        # Create the <singlesymbol> element
        singlesymbol = doc.createElement("singlesymbol")
        maplayer.appendChild(singlesymbol)

        # Create the <symbol> element
        symbol = doc.createElement("symbol")
        singlesymbol.appendChild(symbol)

        # Create the <lowervalue> element
        lowervalue = doc.createElement("lowervalue")
        symbol.appendChild(lowervalue)

        # Create the <uppervalue> element
        uppervalue = doc.createElement("uppervalue")
        symbol.appendChild(uppervalue)

        # Create the <label> element
        label = doc.createElement("label")
        symbol.appendChild(label)

        # Create the <rotationclassificationfieldname> element
        rotationclassificationfieldname = doc.createElement("rotationclassificationfieldname")
        symbol.appendChild(rotationclassificationfieldname)

        # Create the <scaleclassificationfieldname> element
        scaleclassificationfieldname = doc.createElement("scaleclassificationfieldname")
        symbol.appendChild(scaleclassificationfieldname)

        # Create the <symbolfieldname> element
        symbolfieldname = doc.createElement("symbolfieldname")
        symbol.appendChild(symbolfieldname)

         # Create the <outlinecolor> element
        outlinecolor = doc.createElement("outlinecolor")
        outlinecolor.setAttribute("red", "88")
        outlinecolor.setAttribute("blue", "99")
        outlinecolor.setAttribute("green", "37")
        symbol.appendChild(outlinecolor)

         # Create the <outlinestyle> element
        outlinestyle = doc.createElement("outlinestyle")
        outline = doc.createTextNode("SolidLine")
        outlinestyle.appendChild(outline)
        symbol.appendChild(outlinestyle)

         # Create the <outlinewidth> element
        outlinewidth = doc.createElement("outlinewidth")
        width = doc.createTextNode("0.26")
        outlinewidth.appendChild(width)
        symbol.appendChild(outlinewidth)

         # Create the <fillcolor> element
        fillcolor = doc.createElement("fillcolor")
        fillcolor.setAttribute("red", "90")
        fillcolor.setAttribute("blue", "210")
        fillcolor.setAttribute("green", "229")
        symbol.appendChild(fillcolor)

         # Create the <fillpattern> element
        fillpattern = doc.createElement("fillpattern")
        fill = doc.createTextNode("SolidPattern")
        fillpattern.appendChild(fill)
        symbol.appendChild(fillpattern)

         # Create the <texturepath> element
        texturepath = doc.createElement("texturepath")
        texturepath.setAttribute("null", "1")
        symbol.appendChild(texturepath)



map_canvas()
legend_func()
project_layers()


#  Write to qgis file

try:
    f.write(doc.toprettyxml())
finally:
    f.close()

print 'Done'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Struggled a bit for last 2 days. Abandoned XML approach. Able to accomplish first 2 tasks.

Need to check how I can accomplish setting WFS,WCS parameters

1. Create `.qgs` file dynamically
2. Add Legend and Layers to the `.qgs` file and save
3. Set WFS,WCS parameters in the `.qgs` file

## code below

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import string
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtXml import *


#Read input parameters from GP dialog
strProjetName = "C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/QGIS-Web-Client-master/projects/myworld.qgs"

  if os.path.isfile(strProjetName):
       os.remove(strProjetName)

  def add_Layers():
      QGISAPP = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)     
      QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis", True)
      QgsApplication.initQgis()     
      QgsProject.instance().setFileName(strProjetName)
      print QgsProject.instance().fileName()


for file1 in os.listdir(r"C:\myprojects\world"):
     if file1.endswith('.shp'):
         layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\myprojects\world"+r"\\"+file1, file1, "ogr")
         print file1
         print layer.isValid()
         # Add layer to the registry
         QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)


QgsProject.instance().write()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()

add_Layers()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the above code to work. I don't know if it's based on an older API or if it was run in QGIS, but here's some code that works as a standalone script. It uses rasters instead of vectors but the idea is the same.

```
import glob
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsRasterLayer,\
    QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsApplication)
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

strProjectName = "my_project.qgs"
raster_directory = "/path/to/rasters/"

# start the qgis application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# start a project
project = QgsProject.instance()
project_path = QFileInfo(strProjectName)

# add files to the project and register them
for filename in glob.glob(raster_directory + "**jp2"):
    split_fname = os.path.split(filename)
    basename = os.path.splitext(split_fname[1])[0]
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(filename, basename)
    if not layer.isValid():
        print("file {} is not a valid raster file".format(split_fname[1]))
    # Add layer to the registry
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# write the project file
project.write(project_path)

# stop qgis
qgs.exitQgis()
```

The QGIS API sure is a weird beast.

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/134377) talks a little about how to group things which is something you might be wanting to do if you're generating QGIS project files programmatically.

Comment: QgsMapLayerRegistry has been deprecated, use QgsProject. To get this to work on MacOS you need to edit your .bash_profile as described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291579/cannot-run-external-scripts-with-qgis-3-2-on-mac-os-x-10-12/295288#295288