# QGIS 2.6 properties per plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6

How can i set a projectproperty with a python plugin? I like to activate the legendfilter for Nodes with existing feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a comment but I have not enough rep.

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130445/64955) might help you. You need to use the [QgsProject](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html) class which has a `writeEntry()` member function. You can get the current project with `QgsProject.instance()`.