# Cannot run external scripts with QGIS 3.2 on Mac OS X 10.12

Tags: installation, qgis-3, mac

I am trying to move some automation out of the GUI and into some external python scripts, and I am having a challenge getting a script to run in Terminal.

I have a fully functioning install of QGIS 3.2, can run commands in the console in app etc.

But trying even a basic hello world crashes when I try to run it:  the following:

```
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

produces this error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone have a workaround or specific list of bash_profile variables to have things set up correctly?  Do I need to import Qt or similar in the script (this was pulled directly from the QGIS Documentation site)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Following [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg40317.html), I made it work by setting `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` in bash (e.g. from Terminal: `nano ~/.bash_profile` and add the line below).

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/Plugins
```