# Is it possible to create a QGIS workspace with pre-loaded layers, styles and print templates with Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am building a python tool which aggregates data from a number of sources and generates some web-maps from this data. I was wondering if it is possible (maybe using PyQGIS) to create a QGIS3 workspace in a specified directory with the layers and styles pre-loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further digging I've found that this is possible, details and sample code in this answer [creating a qgis project file from pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/272104/59058)