# Create QGIS Workspace Template

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, template

We are rolling QGIS out to a number of departments in my company that have never used QGIS (or any GIS system) before. I was wondering if there is a way to create a QGIS workspace template with pre-set Panels and Toolbars, Favorited Symbology, Connected Basemaps, etc. to make the process as easy as possible for everyone?

Comment: Cool idea, I might take a look at using the QGIS API in a stand alone script, distribute QGIS and then run the script to set everything up. Here are some other similar Q&A that might help you get started in the right direction. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298427/is-it-possible-to-create-a-qgis-workspace-with-pre-loaded-layers-styles-and-pri), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130117/qgis-python-script-for-creating-project-file/272104#272104), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/adding-layer-group-using-pyqgis/134377#134377)